# Consumir WebService passando objeto como parametro

Tags: java, web-service, wildfly, wsdl, jax-ws

Tenho o WebService e envio o objeto `Cliente` como paramentro, gostaria de saber como posso fazer isso funcionar, e ele criar um WSDL adequando quando executo o Server, para que eu posso fazer a chamada em um WebService Cliente.

```
@WebService
public interface UCClienteWS {
    @WebMethod public Cliente cadastrarCliente(Cliente cli);
    @WebMethod public Cliente obterTelefonesDoCliente(Cliente cli);
    @WebMethod public Cliente obterClientePorID(Cliente cli);
    @WebMethod public Cliente obterClientePorNome(Cliente cli);
    @WebMethod public boolean excluirClientePorID(Cliente cli);
    @WebMethod public ArrayList<Cliente> obterTodosClientes();
}
```

.

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "webservice.cliente.UCClienteWS")
public class UCClienteImpl implements UCClienteWS{

    @Override
    public Cliente cadastrarCliente(Cliente cli) {
        UCCliente ucCliente = new UCCliente();
        return ucCliente.cadastrarCliente(cli);
    }

    @Override
    public Cliente obterTelefonesDoCliente(Cliente cli) {
        UCCliente ucCliente = new UCCliente();
        return ucCliente.obterTelefonesDoCliente(cli);
    }

    @Override
    public Cliente obterClientePorID(Cliente cli) {
        UCCliente ucCliente = new UCCliente();
        return ucCliente.obterClientePorID(cli);
    }

    @Override
    public Cliente obterClientePorNome(Cliente cli) {
        UCCliente ucCliente = new UCCliente();
        return ucCliente.obterClientePorNome(cli);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean excluirClientePorID(Cliente cli) {
        UCCliente ucCliente = new UCCliente();
        return ucCliente.excluirClientePorID(cli);
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Cliente> obterTodosClientes() {
        UCCliente ucCliente = new UCCliente();
        return ucCliente.obterTodosClientes();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, vou compartilhar com vc como que eu uso um WS a partir de uma aplicação cliente.

Bom, vamos começar a missa. :-D

Existe uma ferramenta que já vem dentro do JDK que é simples, facil e de graça para vc gerar as classes cliente (consumidora) do seu Web service. É a ferramenta **wsimport** via linha de comando DOS(Windos) ou no terminal(Linux). Verifique se  o JAVA_HOME esta configurado em suas variaveis de sistema, se não estiver, vc terá que add JAVA_HOME em suas variaveis de ambiente.

Bom vamos ao que interessa. :-D

Vou considerar que seu Web service já esta desenvolvido e pronto para ser consumido e que já esta publicado.

1- acesso o seu serviço pelo browser como por exemplo http://ingo.com/myapp/UCClienteWS?wsdl

2- salvo essa URL com extensão .wsdl como UCClienteWS.wsdl (salve de preferencia dentro de sua aplicação cliente, pois se estiver usando SVN ou outra coisa, ja fica versionado.)

3- acesso o cmd ou terminal (de acordo com seu ambiente) e vai até onde seu arquivo wsdl esta salvado.

4- digite `wsimport -keep -verbose UCClienteWS.wsdl` isso vai criar uma estrutura de pastas para vc com as classes cliente dentro.

5- copie e cole essa pasta (package) para dentro de sua aplicação cliente.

6- chamando os metodos e passando seu objeto:

6.1- Dentro dessa estrutura foi criado uma Classe Cliente que é o objeto que o serviço aceita. Nessa classe tem umas anotações dizendo que ela vai virar um objeto XML quando enviada para o serviço.

6.2- chamando o serviço

```
Cliente cli = new Cliente();
cli.setNome("Zé");
cli.setRenda("1.000.000,00");

UCClienteWSService service = new UCClienteWSService();
UCClienteWS ucCliente= UCClienteWSService .getUCClienteWSPort();

ucCliente.cadastrarCliente(cli);
```

É por ai o caminho.

Qualquer busque no google algo sobre wsimport. è susse. Espero que tenha ajudado.

Abraço..